WPF how to put text from Selected Item in ComboBox into Selected Cells in DataGrid when both are connected to Database?
I'm creating a program that will allow the user to Assign Jobs a number of Jobs to a Name through the use of WPF. I am using a ComboBox for the name and a DataGrid for the Jobs. They are both tied to a database through MySQLConnector. But I can't seem to find a way to add what is selected in the ComboBox into the selected Cells in the DataGrid.
My Xaml code is as follows:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Assign_Jobs"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Assign Jobs" Height="1018" Width="1836"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,-16">
        <ComboBox Name="Name"  DisplayMemberPath="Username" Height="34" Margin="48,90,1540,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>
        <DataGrid Name="Job" Height="774" Margin="355,88,918,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Margin="48,51,1581,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please Select Picker:"  Width="207" Foreground="#FFFFFEFE"/>
        <TextBlock Height="17" Margin="355,51,1301,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please Select Jobs:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button Content="Assign" Click="Assign" Height="56" Margin="0,0,10,28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="117"/>
        <Button Content="Back" Click="Back" Height="56" Margin="0,0,155,28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="117"/>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="772" Margin="1132,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="1132,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Assigned Jobs:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button Content="Job Asc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="1564,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <Button Content="Job Desc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="1686,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <Button Content="Picker Asc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="1564,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <Button Content="Picker Desc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="1686,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <Button Content="Time Asc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="1564,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <Button Content="Time Desc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="1686,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="1564,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sort By:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

My C# code is as following:
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Assign_Jobs.xaml
    /// </summary>
    
    public partial class Assign_Jobs : Window
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        public Assign_Jobs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Username from pp1_users", connection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM pp1_jobs", connection))
                {

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                    ad.Fill(dt2);

                    Name.DataContext = dt;
                    Name.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    Job.DataContext = dt2;
                    Job.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
                }
            }
        }
        private void Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Close();
            MainWindow subWindow = new MainWindow();
            subWindow.Show();
            Close();
        }

        private void Assign(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM pp1_jobs", connection))
            {
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

                ad.Fill(dt2);
                Job.DataContext = dt2;
                Job.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
                Job.BeginEdit();
                Job[Job.SelectedCells]

                connection.Close();
                
            }
            Assign_Jobs subWindow = new Assign_Jobs();
            subWindow.Show();
            Close();
        }

    }
}

The idea is to pull what was picked in the ComboBox and put it in however many Cells that are Selected of the DataGrid when the Assign button is pressed. The Column of the Selected Cells will always be the same as well so if clicking anywhere on the Row and having it place it on the certain Column on the selected Row would work better that would be great.
I tried setting it to Edit and trying from there but it wouldn't let me enter the elected rows
Job.BeginEdit();
Job[Job.SelectedCells] = Name.Text;

But it will not allow me to use the Brackets.

You need some sort of intermediatiary on the comboBox to be Bound to the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox, you then tie this intermediate object back to the datagrid to populate the Jobs. This is usually a job for a ViewModel utilizing the MVVM pattern, and shouldnt really be done directly with the database objects as I highly doubt your corresponding database class objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged (which things need to do for UI interaction)
